# Deleting from within the edit page

Tags: laravel-backpack

Hi I'm trying to make it so I can have a delete button within the edit page to just directly delete whatever crud resource is being edited, now I began with taking a look at the list view and trying to reverse engineer the jQuery stuff that creates the delete buttons in the list and for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it. I tried grabbing the blade code in the delete.blade.php view and when I click the button that generates I get a 403 forbidden error. Now I was thinking I could continue messing with the jQuery but shouldn't that delete button code also work? My conclusion so far is I'm missing something stupidly obvious regarding permissions maybe? We're running the crud permissions package as well, would that impact anything? It's weird because I have the button in the 
`@if ($crud->hasAccess('delete'))`

checking stuff so shouldn't that mean I already have permissions? I sure can delete the items from the list view still.

Sorry if I'm confusing, I'm a bit of a super tired dad and could use some help :p

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're pointing the AJAX call in the right direction?

The `list.blade.js` javascript points to the current page, because it's the same URL, just a different protocol. If you place it on another page, it won't work as-is. You have to point it to `$this->crud->route`, still using the DELETE method. So something like this:

```
  function register_delete_button_action() {
    $("[data-button-type=delete]").unbind('click');
    // CRUD Delete
    // ask for confirmation before deleting an item
    $("[data-button-type=delete]").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var delete_button = $(this);
      var delete_url = '{{ url($this->crud->route) }}'; <---- notice the change here

      if (confirm("{{ trans('backpack::crud.delete_confirm') }}") == true) {
          $.ajax({
              url: delete_url,
              type: 'DELETE',
              success: function(result) {
                  // Show an alert with the result
                  new PNotify({
                      title: "{{ trans('backpack::crud.delete_confirmation_title') }}",
                      text: "{{ trans('backpack::crud.delete_confirmation_message') }}",
                      type: "success"
                  });
                  // delete the row from the table
                  delete_button.parentsUntil('tr').parent().remove();
              },
              error: function(result) {
                  // Show an alert with the result
                  new PNotify({
                      title: "{{ trans('backpack::crud.delete_confirmation_not_title') }}",
                      text: "{{ trans('backpack::crud.delete_confirmation_not_message') }}",
                      type: "warning"
                  });
              }
          });
      } else {
          new PNotify({
              title: "{{ trans('backpack::crud.delete_confirmation_not_deleted_title') }}",
              text: "{{ trans('backpack::crud.delete_confirmation_not_deleted_message') }}",
              type: "info"
          });
      }
    });
  }
```